# confusing about hg webserver

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I've some local mercurial repository to my pc and I want that a thirt person can clone it. I cannot use Google code. What can I do? I've tryed to simply go to my local repository and start the web server. Now from my browser I edit both `localhost:8000` and `myipaddress:8000` and this work just fine. I also tryed to clone from command line the repository: `hg clone http://myipaddress:8000` myhgrep and this work fine too.

I've tryed tha same thing from another pc: on my host (server) pc I started the webserve, in the other pc I've tryed to type serveripaddress:8000 but it doesn't work!

What I am wrong? Is a very simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: firewall? routing? different networks? no way to tell.

Comment: why not use bitbucket.org?

Comment: Is it secure and safe?

Comment: yes and you can have private repositories. And it's free.